# ImageMagick: Layering Images with convert -composite with gravity center

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, overlay, composite

[image]

background

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wA2EL.png]

overlay

```
composite -gravity center overlay.png  background.jpg  result1.jpg
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XgdA2.jpg]

result1.jpg

```
convert -composite background.jpg overlay.png -gravity center result2.jpg
```

[image]

result2.jpg

```
convert -composite background.jpg -gravity center tool_marker.png  result3.jpg
```

[image]

result3.jpg

How can I achieve the results from result1 while using convert as the executable rather than composite?

Thanks!

Comment: convert  background.jpg tool_marker.png -gravity center -composite  result4.jpg

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can start by using the operators in the right order. That is set the 'settings' first.
"Composite" command is 'read all settings then apply ONE operation, type of command (traditional UNIX)
"Convert" is a 'do options as you see them', with MULTIPLE operations possible. (script-like command)

```
convert  background.jpg  tool_marker.png -geometry +50+50 -composite result4.jpg
```

Note the +50+50 is the location of the top-left corner of the 'tool_marker.png" image. You will need to subtract the 'pin-point' location in that image to get it to pin point in the right location.

Gravity Center (if given BEFORE the -composite operation that uses it), aligns the center of BOTH images.

```
convert background.jpg tool_marker.png -gravity center -composite result4.jpg
```

Comment: How would you add 2 pins to the image?